# Cassandra 3.10 Create Trigger, class doesn't exist

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I have DSE 5.1 with Cassandra 3.10 and cql 5.0.1 installed on CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core).

I'm following the tutorial from DSE Triggers:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateTrigger.html?hl=trigger

Which send me to github:
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers

According to the tutorial, I am compiling the jar with ANT 1.10.1. The compiled jar contain the code:

```
package org.apache.cassandra.triggers;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.cassandra.schema.TableMetadata;
import org.apache.cassandra.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.Partition;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate;
import org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils;
import org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities;
import org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen;

public class AuditTrigger implements ITrigger
{
    private Properties properties = loadProperties();

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update)
    {
        String auditKeyspace = properties.getProperty("keyspace");
        String auditTable = properties.getProperty("table");

        TableMetadata metadata = Schema.instance.getTableMetadata(auditKeyspace, auditTable);
        PartitionUpdate.SimpleBuilder audit = PartitionUpdate.simpleBuilder(metadata, UUIDGen.getTimeUUID());

        audit.row()
             .add("keyspace_name", update.metadata().keyspace)
             .add("table_name", update.metadata().table)
             .add("primary_key", update.metadata().partitionKeyType.getString(update.partitionKey().getKey()));

        return Collections.singletonList(audit.buildAsMutation());
    }

    private static Properties loadProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream stream = AuditTrigger.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AuditTrigger.properties");
        try
        {
            properties.load(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            FileUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

The compiled jar, I am copying to the cassandra triggers location (/etc/cassandra/triggers). Then I run from cql the command:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1 ON test.test USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger';
```

And send me the error:

```
ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist
```

I copied the jar in all the nodes of my cluster, restarted the cluster and ran the command:

```
nodetool reloadtriggers
```

With no success, I also put in the jvm.options the command:

```
-Dcassandra.triggers_dir=/etc/dse/cassandra/triggers
```

And in the cassandra-env.sh, I added the command:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.triggers_dir=/etc/dse/cassandra/triggers"
```

And I am getting the same error. I tryied adding the jar in the cassandra lib folder (/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/) and it seems to not been loading the compiled jar.

When I run the command in cql:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER test1 ON test.test USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger';
```

I am still getting the same error

```
ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist
```

So, my question is, How can I make cassandra load my jar correctly and use it to create a trigger in cql?

Comment: Try this command `nodetool reloadtriggers` and check the cassandra `system.log`

Comment: I use the command and only send me this line:

INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] 2017-05-19 18:48:34,484  CustomClassLoader.java:89 - Loading new jar /etc/dse/cassandra/triggers/trigger-example.jar

Comment: Then trigger jar loaded successfully​. Now use create trigger command

Comment: Same error:

ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist

Comment: Did you check the package name, match with your jar package name ? and also if you are using cluster, you have to put the jar on every node

Comment: Or may be your jar is not build correctly

Comment: I put the jar on every node and I check the jar package name, it is ok. How can the build be incorrect?

Comment: @Ashraful Islam  I checked the jar and the main class was missing, then I added the main class: org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger. I copied the jar to all the nodes of the cluster, restarted the cluster, ran the nodetool reload triggers command (It is loading the jar) but I got the same error: ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist

Comment: @JoaGacs, I am also running into same problem. could you please help me on this, if this is working for you now ?.

Comment: I solved it using an external java development, Couldn't spend more time making the trigger work